# Create html file from webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file

I am having trouble figuring this out. In fact, I really don't know where to start. I need to figure out how my website can make a file (HTML or Text!!!) and then download it. Sort of like how Google Docs make the file of you document, and then you can download it. The code needs to be in HTML and javascript. JQuery is fine too. Thanks!

Comment: What kind of file? Depending on the format, the solution you want could go from difficult to impossible.

Comment: In php you can create a file with 
file_put_contents("filename.extension", "content");
Hope it help

Comment: Hmm. You might struggle doing this on the client-side. It will be possible in the future when things like the `download` attribute for `<a>` elements is fully supported (you will be able to put the dynamically-generated file data in the link's `href` value, base64 encoded - cool, eh?). In the meantime, your server-side application will need to take on some responsibility here, e.g. for returning the correct HTTP headers. Anyway, we'll need more specific details about the functionality of your application to figure this out. :)

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this reliably without a server-side technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the kind of file you would like to make.
I made a little snippet that shows how to create plain text and binary (in this case an image) files.

```js
var textData = new Blob(['My file content'], {type: 'text/plain'});
var myTextFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(textData);
document.getElementById('downloadText').href = myTextFile;

var base64Data = "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";

var binaryData = atob(base64Data);
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(binaryData.length);
var byteArray = new Uint8Array(buffer);
for (var i = 0; i < binaryData.length; i++)
    byteArray[i] = binaryData.charCodeAt(i);

var imageData = new Blob([byteArray], {type: 'image/png'});
var myImage = window.URL.createObjectURL(imageData);
document.getElementById('downloadImage').href = myImage;
```

```html
<a id="downloadText" download="filename.txt">Download Text File</a><br />
<a id="downloadImage" download="image.png">Download Image</a>
```